Upload public key to GCP using terraform
According to the terraform documentation (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_key):
public_key_data (Optional) Public key data to create a service account key for given service account. The expected format for this field is a base64 encoded X509_PEM and it conflicts with public_key_type and private_key_type.

Apparently its possible to upload a public key to a GCP service account. I'm trying to do exactly that.
I generated a private/public key pair using openssl:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 \
    -keyout /path/to/private_key.pem \
    -out /path/to/public_key.pem \
    -subj "/CN=unused"

I then took that public key, eliminated the header, footer and newlines, then pasted it to a file and fed that file to Terraform:
resource "google_service_account_key" "service-account-key" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.api-service-account.name
  public_key_data = file("../public_keys/certificate.pem")
}

This validated fine. But when Terraform tried to create the resource, I got this error:
╷
│ Error: Error creating service account key: googleapi: Error 400: The given public key data is invalid., badRequest
│ 
│   with google_service_account_key.service-account-key,
│   on main.tf line XX, in resource "google_service_account_key" "service-account-key":
│   XX: resource "google_service_account_key" "service-account-key" {
│ 
╵

I have tried everything I can think of:

Hardcoding the key

Not removing the footer and header

Not removing the newlines

Removing them but programattically

Encoding it programatically with terraform

Decoding it programatically with terraform

Generating a certificate using:


openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key private_key.pem -out certificate.pem -days 365 -subj "/CN=unused"


Then I tried everything again with the certificate.


I verified the key and its a valid base64, so that's not the issue. The format should be x509 too, so I don't think that's the issue either. But I'm out of ideas at this point.
I can't find a single proper, complete example on the internet, and I'm out of ideas.

Do not modify anything. The contents of public_key.pem is what you should use. If you have continued problems, verify that the CLI accepts the file. See the example here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-upload#iam-service-accounts-upload-gcloud Edit your post, remove all the junk and update based on my comment.

Although the PEM file you created contains a base64 public key, Google expects the whole file to be base64 encoded (so including the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- / -----END CERTIFICATE----- )
Change :
resource "google_service_account_key" "service-account-key" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.api-service-account.name
  public_key_data = file("../public_keys/certificate.pem")
}

to:
resource "google_service_account_key" "service-account-key" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.api-service-account.name
  public_key_data = filebase64("../public_keys/certificate.pem")
}

and it will work.

You were right. I actually solved this by manually encoding it and then feeding the new encoded file to Terraform, but of course your solution is cleaner.
Thank you!
